# How can I make toggle-truncate-lines work in narrow windows?

Tags: truncate-lines

With toggle-truncate-lines, there seems to be a limit on the width of the window when this setting works. If the window is smaller than allowed, it doesn't seem to work.

How can I remove this limit?

Comment: Did you read `C-h f toggle-truncate-lines`?

Comment: ah, great;), so (setq truncate-partial-width-windows 0) thanks

Comment: You're welcome; but if you're not using `C-h f` and `C-h v` (or `C-h o`) as a *habit* by now (your profile says "Member for 7 years, 8 months" with ~140 questions under your belt), something has gone rather awry.  Make "asking Emacs" your first step whenever you have a question.

Comment: Right, too quick on that one;). Generally, I'm good at searching.

Comment: Comments are ephemeral. How about self-answering and accepting to close this question out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you do it;)

```lisp
(setq truncate-partial-width-windows 0)
```

Comment: Please mark this answer as accepted, thank you.

Comment: You can accept your own answer in 12 hours, it says.

Comment: I got the timing wrong, my bad :D